# sort array contents into alphabetised groups/columns

Tags: php, arrays, list

PHP array containing all the cities in Italy (done this)

Generate a list of all the cities starting with the letter G, B and I grouped in columns. (can't figure out how to do this) I have already made the columns and headings. just need to get the data into the columns.

```
$cities = array("Rome", "Milan", "Turin", "Naples", "Venice-Padua", "Florence",

    "Bari", "Palermo", "Catania",

    "Brescia", "Genoa", "Messina-Reggio Calabria", "Rimini", "Bologna", "Modena",

    "Verona", "Pisa-livorno", "Pescara",

    "Versilia", "Vicenza", "Cagliari", "Taranto", "Trieste", "Ancona", "Perugia",

    "Lecce", "Reggio nell'Emilia" ) ;





    ?>

    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-push-2">

    <h1>Cties starting with G</h1>
        <p></p>


   </div>
```

that's what I've got so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
foreach($cities as $data){
    if(substr($data,0, 1)=="G"){
        echo $data."</br>";
    }
}

foreach($cities as $data){
    if(substr($data,0, 1)=="B"){
        echo $data."</br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach` loop and a simple check:

```
<div class = "col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-push-2">
    <h1>Cities starting with B</h1>
    <?php
        foreach ($cities as $city):
          if ($city[0] == "B"):
    ?>
    <p><?= $city;?></p>
    <?php
          endif;
        endforeach;
    ?>
</div>

<div class = "col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-push-2">
    <h1>Cities starting with G</h1>
    <?php
        foreach ($cities as $city):
          if ($city[0] == "G"):
    ?>
    <p><?= $city;?></p>
    <?php
          endif;
        endforeach;
    ?>
</div>
```